# ASP.NET C# Web Service Oracle package returns empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio-2010, web-services

I have Oracle package procedure which takes XML string as an input variable and outputs XML string. I'm trying to write a web service but it returns empty string (null) instead of the XML string.

Code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string packageCall(string xmlStr)
    {
        OracleConnection oraCon = new OracleConnection();
        oraCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source="+database+";User Id="+ userId+";Password="+pass+";";
        oraCon.Open();
        OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand("PKG_WEBSERV11.TEST",oraCon);
        objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objCmd.Parameters.Add("P_IN", xmlStr.ToString());
        objCmd.Parameters.Add("P_OUT", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        try
        {
            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string result = "<!--[CDATA] "+objCmd.Parameters["P_OUT"].Value +" -->";
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error: +"+ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            oraCon.Close();
        }
    }
```

Package:

```
    PKG_WEBSERV11
    PROCEDURE TEST (P_IN IN VARCHAR2, P_OUT OUT VARCHAR2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After staring at the code for a few hours I realised the solution is a lot more simple than anticipated!

```
objCmd.Parameters.Add("P_IN", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = xmlStr;
```